# Java connection to MS Access Database

Tags: java, sql, database, ms-access, jdbc-odbc

Just wondering if anyone cane help me, I'm trying to connect to an MS Access Database. I have done it on other projects and used exactly the same code. Can anyone see if I have done anything wrong?

```
try {
        System.out.println("Attempting Database Connection");
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String sourceURL = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb)};DBQ=MotivationDatabase.mdb;";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(sourceURL, "", "");
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Connection made");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Database connection attempt failed");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

I keep getting the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not find file '(unknown)'.
```

But my database is in the same folder as my project like I've done before s I'm not sure why i am getting this error. Help?

Comment: You need to specify the **full** path to the .mdb file in the JDBC URL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: He is not using JDBC.

Comment: @Sandeep: of course he/she is. It's the JDBC/ODBC bridge that is being used, but it's still JDBC

Answer (score 2):

- `Control Panel` -> `Administrative Tools` -> `ODBC Data Sources` -> `Add` -> `Microsoft Access Driver(*mdb,*accdb)`
- Specify the correct path to `MotivationDatabase.mdb` corresponding to `Data Source name` and save the settings.

Refer **[here](http://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb00686.html)**.

[image]

### Code:

```
public class Main {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Attempting Database Connection");
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String sourceURL = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="
            + "D:\\MotivationDatabase.mdb";
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(sourceURL);
            System.out.println("Connection made");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

### Output:

[image]

**P.S:** Please learn to work with **[JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html)** as **[JDBC-ODBC Bridge will be removed in JDK8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html)**.See **[here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/build-dev/2012-October/007090.html)**.

### EDIT:

You can also use JDBC along with **[UCanAccess API](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html)** to connect to an MSAccess database. You would need the following jars in your project build path.

1. commons-lang-2.6.jar
2. commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
3. hsqldb.jar
4. jackcess-2.1.0.jar
5. ucanaccess-2.0.9.5.jar

### Code:

```
connection = DriverManager
.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess:////REMOTE-IP-ADDRESS/shared-folder/TestDB.mdb");
System.out.println("CONNECTION ESTABLISHED....");
```

Works fine with JDK8. You can download the entire source code from **[here](https://pastebin.com/tbAQDD4U)**.

Comment: I've already done this and still the same error, I'm at a loss to where I've gone wrong if I'm honest.

Answer (score 0):

Sun JDBC ODBC will notte work with MS access when java 8 will ne release: I suggest you to use apache poi project. It s simple and works great.

Yeah it's correct the right project is jakcess:

```
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Row;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Table;
try{Table table = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("filename")).getTable("tablename");
    righe.add(0);
    for(Row row : table) {
        String articolo=row.get("ColName").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this class forename and connection URL.Add the below jar files to your projects:

commons-lang.jar,commons-logging.jar,hsqldb.jar,jackcess.jar,ucanaccess.jar

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
//change the path with your own accdb file
String URL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://D:\\projects\\test.accdb";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
```